# Understanding Number of StreamProcessor instances created and do stream task share same streamprocessor instance?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to understand a little more details on the relationship between `StreamThread`, `StreamTask` and how many instances of `StreamProcessor` is created when we have:

- a source kafka topic with multiple partitions , say 6.
- I am keeping only **ONE** `StreamThread` (num.stream.threads=1)

I am keeping a simple processor topology:

source_topic --> Processor1 --> Processor2 --> Processo3 --> sink_topic

Each processor simply forwards to next processor in chain. Snippet of one of the processors. I am using low level Java API.

```
public class Processor1 implements Processor<String, String> {

    private ProcessorContext context;
    public Processor1() {
    
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context
    }

    @Override
    public void punctuate(long timestamp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void process(String key, String value) {
        System.out.println("Inside Processor1#process() method");
        context.forward(key, value);
    }
}
```

**Snippet of Main driver application:**

```
Topology topology = new Topology();

topology.addSource("SOURCE", "source-topic-data");
topology.addProcessor("Processor1", () -> new Processor1(), "SOURCE");
topology.addProcessor("Processor2", () -> new Processor2(), "Processor1");
topology.addProcessor("Processor3", () -> new Processor3(), "Processor2");
topology.addSink("SINK", "sink-topic-data", "Processor3");

Properties settings = new Properties();
settings.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 1);
StreamsConfig config = new StreamsConfig(settings);
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, config);
streams.start();
```

With this arrangement, I have following questions:

- How many instances of processors (`Processor1`, `Processor2`, `Processor3`) will be created?
- As per my understanding , there will be `SIX stream tasks`. Is a new instance of processor created for each `Stream task` or they "share" the same `Processor instance`?
- When a `Stream Thread` is created, does it create a new instance of `processor`?
- Are `Stream Tasks` created as part of `Stream Threads` creation?

(New question added to original list)

- In this scenario a `single stream thread` will have  `SIX stream tasks`. Does a `stream thread` execute these `stream tasks` one-by-one, sort of "in-a-loop". Do `stream tasks` run as a separate "thread". Basically, not able to understand how a `single stream thread` run multiple `stream tasks` at the same time/in parallel?

**The below is topology which gets printed:**

```
KafkaStreams processID: 1602fe25-57ab-4620-99df-fd0c15d96e42
    StreamsThread appId: my-first-streams-application
        StreamsThread clientId: my-first-streams-application-1602fe25-57ab-4620-99df-fd0c15d96e42
        StreamsThread threadId: my-first-streams-application-1602fe25-57ab-4620-99df-fd0c15d96e42-StreamThread-1
        Active tasks:
            Running:                                StreamsTask taskId: 0_0
                                            ProcessorTopology:
                            SOURCE:
                                topics:     [source-topic-data]
                                children:   [Processor1]
                            Processor1:
                                children:   [Processor2]
                            Processor2:
                                children:   [Processor3]
                            Processor3:
                                children:   [SINK]
                            SINK:
                                topic:      sink-topic-data
                    Partitions [source-topic-data-0]
                                StreamsTask taskId: 0_1
                                            ProcessorTopology:
                            SOURCE:
                                topics:     [source-topic-data]
                                children:   [Processor1]
                            Processor1:
                                children:   [Processor2]
                            Processor2:
                                children:   [Processor3]
                            Processor3:
                                children:   [SINK]
                            SINK:
                                topic:      sink-topic-data
                    Partitions [source-topic-data-1]
                                StreamsTask taskId: 0_2
                                            ProcessorTopology:
                            SOURCE:
                                topics:     [source-topic-data]
                                children:   [Processor1]
                            Processor1:
                                children:   [Processor2]
                            Processor2:
                                children:   [Processor3]
                            Processor3:
                                children:   [SINK]
                            SINK:
                                topic:      sink-topic-data
                    Partitions [source-topic-data-2]
                                StreamsTask taskId: 0_3
                                            ProcessorTopology:
                            SOURCE:
                                topics:     [source-topic-data]
                                children:   [Processor1]
                            Processor1:
                                children:   [Processor2]
                            Processor2:
                                children:   [Processor3]
                            Processor3:
                                children:   [SINK]
                            SINK:
                                topic:      sink-topic-data
                    Partitions [source-topic-data-3]
                                StreamsTask taskId: 0_4
                                            ProcessorTopology:
                            SOURCE:
                                topics:     [source-topic-data]
                                children:   [Processor1]
                            Processor1:
                                children:   [Processor2]
                            Processor2:
                                children:   [Processor3]
                            Processor3:
                                children:   [SINK]
                            SINK:
                                topic:      sink-topic-data
                    Partitions [source-topic-data-4]
                                StreamsTask taskId: 0_5
                                            ProcessorTopology:
                            SOURCE:
                                topics:     [source-topic-data]
                                children:   [Processor1]
                            Processor1:
                                children:   [Processor2]
                            Processor2:
                                children:   [Processor3]
                            Processor3:
                                children:   [SINK]
                            SINK:
                                topic:      sink-topic-data
                    Partitions [source-topic-data-5]

            Suspended:
            Restoring:
            New:
        Standby tasks:
            Running:
            Suspended:
            Restoring:
            New:
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the Topology?

Comment: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-kafka-streams/kafka-streams-internals-StreamTask.html

Comment: @cricket_007: After waiting for a while it prints topology correctly. But how can I know how many Processors instances were created and other info from this topology output?

Comment: I was thinking this would help https://zz85.github.io/kafka-streams-viz/

Comment: @cricket_007: I got the point, it shows info like StreamTasks, active tasks etc., but how can I know overall how many Processor instances were created etc. I am still learning, and of course, going thru the code (I am on learning curve so it is taking time for me to understand by looking into kafka code). Thanks for your help

Comment: Every record flows through each processor (unless filtered out), so 6 partitions * 3 processors , is what I'm going with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How many instances of processors (Processor1, Processor2, Processor3) will be created?

In your example, six each. Each task will instantiate a full copy of the `Topology`. (cf. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.4/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/StreamThread.java#L355; note: a `Topology` is a the logical representation of the program, and is instantiated as`ProcessorTopology` at runtime)

> As per my understanding, there will be SIX stream tasks. Is a new instance of processor created for each Stream task or they "share" the same Processor instance?

Each task has its own `Processor` instance -- they are not shared.

> When a Stream Thread is created, does it create a new instance of processor?

No. When a task is created, it will create new `Processor` instances.

> Are Stream Tasks created as part of Stream Threads creation?

No. Tasks are create during a rebalance according to the partition/task assignment. KafkaStreams registers a `StreamsRebalanceListener` on its internal cosumner that call `TaskManager#createTasks()`

*Update (as question was extended):*

> In this scenario a single stream thread will have SIX stream tasks. Does a stream thread execute these stream tasks one-by-one, sort of "in-a-loop". Do stream tasks run as a separate "thread". Basically, not able to understand how a single stream thread run multiple stream tasks at the same time/parallely?

Yes, the `StreamsThread` will execute the tasks in a loop. There are no other threads. Hence, tasks that are assigned to the same thread are not executed at the same time/in-parallel but one after each other.(Cf. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.4/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/AssignedStreamsTasks.java#L472 -- each `StreamThread` used exactly one `TaskManager` that uses `AssignedStreamsTasks` and `AssignedStandbyTasks` internally.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, helped to understand. So in this case, there will be `ONE stream thread`, and it will have `SIX stream tasks`, and for each `stream task` there will be `unique instance of processor`. This `single Stream thread` will execute `all SIX stream tasks`. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification. I have one more question, should I ask here or ask a new question? You are expert in this field and I am glad that you are helping to understand.

Comment: Depends -- if it's related, feel free to update your original question and I can update my answer. If it's something different, might be better to do a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added updated the question, the last in the list.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping to understand this. I want to see that piece of code of kafka, if you can, please let me know which source path to look for?

Comment: Thanks a ton, I owe you this gratitude. Best Regards